# TextView as a Button

Tags: android, button, textview

Is there a way i can use TextView as a button and have a way it changed text color under pressed state ?

i am doing this right now

TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ForgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="7pt" />
```

Java Code

```
    forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ForgotPassword);
    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you look in the Button class implementation, you can see that a button is just a TextView with specific style. So everything you can do with a button, be sure you can do with a text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use state drawables as the background to your textView.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: i checked that but looks like list cant take a textColor

Comment: oh, you din't mention the text there. i thought you wanted to change the background of textView. please, edit your question.

Comment: i had this problem earlier, but din't find any, would love to know the solution :), i guess you have to change the color in on click listener.

Comment: saw that u were from Bangalore too. curious where do you work ?

Comment: would love to connect with you.. offline.. are u coming to Droidcon ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this file as textcolor of textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item 
  android:state_pressed="true"
  android:color="colorcode" 
 /> <!-- pressed -->    

 <item 
       android:color="colorcode"
 /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```